# Is function scope already determined in initial compiled even it not run?

Tags: javascript

Here is a file called `index.js`

```js
// index.js
let a = 1;

function foo(name) {
  let b = 2;
}
```

If I run it, I knew that `a` and `foo` is appended to the global scope at the parsing stage. But now I am not running the function `foo`, is the function scope of `foo` determined at parsing time? If it determined, where `name` and `b` placed ?

Actually I got trapped by this problem when reading 'You Don't Know JS Yet - Scope & Closures'. Here is the [link](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/edit/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch2.md), between line 161 and line 171. at that time `getStudentName` is not executed,  but the `studentID` will be found by scope manager.  `getStudenName` like the function `foo` in `index.js`, and `studentID` like `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The scope that contains `name` and `b` are not created until the function `foo()` is called.

Comment: "the scope" - don't you mean "the closure"? Because `a` will exist in the global scope (unless the file is an ES module) - e.g. if a web-page has `index.js` and `index2.js` added via `<script>` elements, then `a` and `foo` would be in-scope inside `index2.js` too.

Comment: @Dai No, I meant the scope. The function scope that contains `name` and `b`, not the global scope that contains `a` and `foo`.

Comment: Ah. I interpreted the question differently.

Comment: Thanks, I knew when `foo()` is called, it will generate an execute context, and `name` and `b` will be create, be put to the memory. 
But I got some doubts when reading 'You don’t know js - scope-closures'. Here is the [link](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/edit/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch2.md), between line 161 and line 171. at that time `getStudentName` is not executed,  but the `studentID` has be found.  why? :<

Comment: @user9081473 That doesn't really make sense, but maybe it's just the fault of the metaphor. Maybe it's better explained by "*Compiler will produce code that (at execution time) asks Scope Manager to create a new variable*" above the conversation. Of course, the compiler/engine might have data structures that describe the shape of the scope that is to be created later, and these might be created during the initial parsing run, but they're definitely internal and implementation might vary engine by engine.

Comment: Ahhh, I understander your means, and I found answer in this book's chapter 3. function scope maybe determined in initial complication but never created unless it executed!